# A Non-deprecated variant for AWS S3 resource is not working in Terraform but deprecated option is working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have this configuration for a S3 bucket to deploy a static UI in cloudfront:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "admin-app-s3" {
  bucket = "admin-app-${var.environment}"
  acl    = "public-read"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "admin-app-s3-policy1" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.admin-app-s3.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Id      = "admin-app-${var.environment}-policy1"
    Statement = [
        {
        Sid       = "Stmt##########"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = {
            AWS = ["arn:aws:iam::##########:user/gitlab-deployments"]
            }
        Action    = "s3:*"
        Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::admin-app-${var.environment}/*"
        },
        {
        Sid       = "Stmt##########"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = "*"
        Action    = ["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"]
        Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::admin-app-${var.environment}/*"

        }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "admin-app-configuration1" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.admin-app-s3.bucket

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }
  error_document {
    key = "index.html"
  }
}
```

Is working, however:

> acl    = "public-read"

is deprecated, you have to use the aws_s3_bucket_acl resource instead. But when I replace my code adding the aws_s3_bucket_acl resouce I lost my Access control list (ACL) in the S3 configuration, then the resources can not be loaded in the web browser by permissions issue:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "admin-app-s3" {
  bucket = "admin-app-${var.environment}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "acl1" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.admin-app-s3.id
  acl    = "public-read"
}
```

My cuestion, like the title is Why a Non-deprecated variant for AWS S3 resource is not working in Terraform but depredated option is working??? My code is running now with the deprecated option, but I any moment an update will be required. This is a Terraform issue?

I´m using Terraform v1.2.2 with AWS provider v3.75.2

Comment: It related to the provider version, not Terraform version.

Comment: The AWS provider version is 3.75.2

Answer (score 1):

Fixed upgrading version of the AWS provider for Terraform from 3.75.2 to 4.22.0